# Display PopupWindow while Dialog is showing

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-popupwindow

Premise: with "on top of" I mean "overlaying", with a "higher z-index", so to speak; with "above" I mean "visually above, on the screen".

I guess the question would be "**how to display a PopupWindow on top of the keyboard when a Dialog is showing?**". Following, the situation...

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon) to have Whatsapp-style emojicons in my app. The way it shows the emojicons in place of the soft-keyboard is by displaying a `PopupWindow` on top of it, so that it covers it completely.

To create the emojicon's popup, I need to pass a `View` to the constructor. I tried passing two different views and it doesn't work with either of them. Here's what happens:

- If I pass the dialog's root view (with `getRootView()`), the popupwindow doesn't appear on top of the keyboard, but on top of the dialog. After debugging I understood that it's because the dialog's root view doesn't take the whole screen but exactly the dialog's size. I thought it would be larger because of the fact that the dimmed background behind the dialog occupies all the screen. I was wrong.
  The popup is interact-able and working as it should.
- If I pass the root view of the activity that contains the dialog, the popup not only appears behind the dialog and the dimmed background (thus being impossible to interact with), but also appears above the keyboard! here's a screenshot:

[image: Result with Activity's root view]

Why does it appear there instead of on top of the keyboard? I really don't understand.

I already tried by changing the `windowSoftInputMode` and setting the `PopupWindow`'s "InputMethodMode" to `PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED`, but the results are always the same.

To create and show the popup, the library simply calls

```
public class EmojiconsPopup extends PopupWindow ... {

    ...

    setSize(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, keyBoardHeight);
    ...
    showAtLocation(rootView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

    ...
}
```

when the keyboard is open.

You can see the library's source code from the link I wrote at the beginning, and [here's an open issue about this problem](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/issues/11), in case it may contain additional useful info.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found a solution.
To make a `PopupWindow` overlay the keyboard when a dialog is open, when calling the `showAtLocation(View rootView, int gravity, int x, int y)` method to show the PopupWindow instead of passing "0, 0" as the coordinates we have to pass, for example, "0, -5000". This way, with a low enough integer as the y coordinate, the popup will be displayed correctly at the bottom of the screen instead of at the bottom of the dialog's root view.

The view to pass as the first parameter must be the dialog's root view, of course.

Remember that if you called `setClippingEnabled(false)` on the popup, when you call showAtLocation with such a low y coordinate, it will disappear from the screen. If the popup must stay whole inside the screen, `isClippingEnabled()` must return true.

Answer (score 0):

I was just thinking android may have more root views than the one used to display your content, you may want to try using the view provided by:

```
 getWindow().getDecorView()
```

If that fails then try getting a reference to your root View (the one with your contents) and then:

```
View myRootView=findViewById(R.id.myroot);  myRootView.getRootView();
```

Again if not successful, you may further try getting the root View of the above view going back one by one until it returns no more root views, i.e:

```
myRootView=myRootView.getRootView();
//if it fails go up in hierarchy again, remember to test for null

myRootView=myRootView.getRootView();
//etc..
```

I assume going up the hierarchy once or twice might give something

Comment: I already tried going up the hierarchy but it was several days ago so I don't remember well. I'll try again. Also, yesterday I was about to try with the DecorView but I didn't do it in the end. I'll surely try.

Comment: I tried with the DecorViews and by calling `getRootView()` several times but nothing changed.

Comment: Let me try it myself, I will be back with an answer

Comment: By the way, I tried to show the PopupWindow before showing the dialog  and the popup gets pushed upwards when the keyboard opens. Shouldn't the position of PopupWindows not be affected by such things?

Comment: Their example seem to be working properly with the activity's root view, does the example  work as expected when you run it?

Comment: The example doesn't use a dialog, though. I just implemented the emojicons "keyboard" in the activity that owns the dialog and it works as it should.
I already tried removing the dimmed background from the dialog in case it did something odd, but the popup is still misplaced like before.

Comment: I think I found a solution. I'll write an answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked out, I still dont understand why it worked in the example and failed in your app

Comment: I guess you can try modifying the example to use a dialog with the EmojiconButton and EmojiconEditText in it, to see if you can reproduce my problem.